# List of words after specific character in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having the following string `ABC #products addsl #customers Lkppkkk dkdjsj #testings`
and I would like to output the list of words that are only after `#` like the following:

```
products
customers
testings
```

Please note I am extracting only one word after `#`
so using `String_Split` will extract the complete words between `#` and that what I don't need or should I use cursor.

How can I do it please?

Comment: You might consider MSSQL [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to use `string_split` and massage the results appropriately:

```
declare @string varchar(100)='ABC #products addsl #customers Lkppkkk dkdjsj #testings'

select Replace(value,'#','') 
from (select @string)s(s)
cross apply String_Split(s,' ')
where value like '#%';
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING(value, 2, LEN(value))` might make more sense, same results but seems clearer to me